# OpenAPI generator Maven plugin: what generator to choose if I want to generate an API client with implementation code? Java EE EAP

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Now I know all the possible values:

```
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:4.3.1:generate (generate-api) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] /home/me/code/myapp/target/META-INF/openapi.yaml [0:0]: unexpected error in Open-API generation
org.openapitools.codegen.GeneratorNotFoundException: Can't load config class with name 'jaxrs'
Available:
ada
ada-server
android
....
```

Among the Java ones:

```
java
jaxrs-cxf-client
java-inflector
java-msf4j
java-pkmst
java-play-framework
java-undertow-server
java-vertx
java-vertx-web
jaxrs-cxf
jaxrs-cxf-extended
jaxrs-cxf-cdi
jaxrs-jersey
jaxrs-resteasy
jaxrs-resteasy-eap
jaxrs-spec
```

Which ones are server and which are clients? What if I want to generate code to call an external API, not only API? I am in a JavaEE EAP application. I was using `javars-spec` but it only generates the API interface. I need implementations.

If there's none, then how is the Java 8 preferred way to implement it? It's EAP, not Spring.

And about the missing dependencies, I know that with `<generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>` I can generate a POM in the targets dir and check what are the dependencies to pull in and I need to put them back to my project's pom.xml, even it seems strange for me but anyway.

Comment: First I recommend to upgrade your used openapi-generator-maven-plugin (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/versions) also the question do you already use Java EE Jakarta etc.

Comment: I am not using Jakarta EE and it's legacy code so maybe upgrade to EAP 7 is not possible, it's EAP 6.

Comment: If you're using EAP 6, perhaps you can use RESTEasy client (https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial). That will allow you to work with the interfaces without having any implementation of your own - the RESTEasy client will create that for you. Within EAP you probably don't even need to bundle it in your application, and can mark the dependency as provided.

Comment: "Which ones are server and which are clients?" --> https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/ distinguishes the available generators by type.